# Private Torrent Setup for folders that will add files weekly

Tags: networking, ftp, automation, bittorrent, utorrent

**Scenario:**

Well the title says it all, I am trying to make a torrent server (on company clients) that are on other side of town so that I can get monthly backups of the SQL Server BAK files. Going there and getting it is an option, but its rather far, like few towns over and it wastes resources; time and energy.

**Reason:**

The reason I am not using FTP to get data is because of the internet. It's consumer internet on every branch ( 10 in total ) which means it maxes at around 4Mbps Downlink and 1Mbps Uplink with Electricity Blackouts every few hours. Using torrent will allow me to resume downloads/uploads.

**Problem:**

I have setup a test torrent server using uTorrent on one branch which will be uploading the BAK files to our File Server. Now do I have to regenerate torrent file every time a new BAK is generated in the folder or will it automatically add it self to the torrent file list? AFAIK by reading articles, it doesn't do that. I want that, to automatically update the files list so that I don't have to regenerate the torrent file every month manually. Is there a way to either automate the process or make uTorrent register new files?

Regards

**EDIT:**
Also wanted to ask, which method should I prefer from below, or any other you guy can think of?

**Case 1**: Where I have to use utorrent's own tracker and give each location a fixed IP or Dynamic DNS setup like No-IP
[image: Case 1]

**Case 2**: Where I can setup my own tracker and use this to seed via IP addresses
[image: Case 2]

Comment: A torrent file has a verify specific format and the information about a torrent is specific to the data that it describes. As such you can't easily add and remove files from torrent. You will have to generate a new torrent file each month. You might be able to let the torrent clients pickup the torrent files automatically from a directory.

Comment: @Seth How about magnet URLs?

Comment: @Seth and how can I get the updated torrent file from a remote place, assuming no ftp server on branch?

Comment: What if I create my own tracker to track torrents and changes? I can use our file server for that.

Comment: If you look at the format specification you will find that it's just not meant to be used that way. If you look at the [wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file#Multiple_files) find why. There is information that is dependent on the contents. Did you instead consider using another tool like `rsync` or similar? FTP also supports the resume of uploads.

Comment: Is FTP safe to continue with like Torrents do? Recheck each part and stuff? If I can generate a script that can regenerate/update torrent files with respect to the items present in a folder, how would I let my tracker know that the torrent file is updated now? or is that even possible?

Comment: @Seth BTW I uploaded the diagram of the setup I wish to make, to make it easier to understand. I'm not great with converting ideas to words.

Comment: @Seth would rsync work with windows Systems? our server is linux. And How can I rsync over internet?

Comment: Have you considered using rsync over ssh?

Comment: @Hefewe1zen actually... no... How would I do that?

Comment: @Hefewe1zen please keep in mind, clients are not Linux, they are Windows, Windows XP to be exact. Our software works on XP only. I am in process to move things to W7 though.

Comment: @echo_salik Ah, gotcha.  Deltacopy is another paid option.  Or robocopy maybe, which is free?  At any rate, a little OT, but get off of XP ASAP!!

Comment: @Hefewe1zen belive me when I say, it will be a painfull process. Going over towns just to install Windows. But not the point, is torrenting possible though? Because I will be writing a script to make 7zs of the BAKs so that the data transmission is faster. It I can write a script to make torrent files along with the compression, would it be possible? Assuming a tracker is set.

Comment: I would like to keep it as easy as it can be to avoid commands and automate stuff. Because the people at branches are not heavily computer literate. I have to use team viewer to setup their mails on outlook. So hence the torrent. Most people know torrenting (piracy) here. I can even walk someone through it with rather ease. Hence my push towards torrent. I know it provides me with everything I want.

Comment: **Question**
What if I use public trackers and password protect my 7z files? That would save me the hassle of creating my own private tracker and still have some form of security. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using torrent consists of multiple different parts. Some of which depends on your actual implementation. Parts you would need to have a look at include:

- Torrent files
- Magnet URIs
- Clients
- Trackers
- Peer exchange technologies like DHT

## Torrent Files

A torrent file contains all the important meta information about the torrent. If you look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file#Multiple_files) you can see a decoded example of a torrent file. Note that you have a list of files and the hashes of pieces. If you want to add a file to this structure you will need to modify both files. In this regard the [Wikipedia article on the protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_(protocol)#Creating_and_publishing_torrents) might also be interesting. If you are using a torrent file you can't just add some data to it. If you do change this information you're going to change the hash value of the information section which is used to identify the torrent. As such you will create a new torrent. See also [What exactly is the info_Hash in a torrent file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348678/what-exactly-is-the-info-hash-in-a-torrent-file).

## Torrent Clients

Torrent Clients are part of the user side of using torrents. There are various clients available and some of them offer to automatically pickup torrent files from directories. An example here could be that you have a single file per backup that the other clients pickup. As torrent files are quite small it might be possible to have a script, a common share where they are stored or you might email them later on.

## Magnet URIs

Again the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) has quite a bit of information but is rather technical. Especially since it's not specific to BitTorrent (Magnet can be used for more). A good explanation is offered in [How do BitTorrent magnet links work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844502/how-do-bittorrent-magnet-links-work). It's essentially the same as having a torrent file, it's just that you start with the info hash and need to find a peer who can hand you the actual torrent file.

## Trackers

Trackers are rather dumb pieces of software. They only know which peers are interested in a particular info hash and share that information with other peers that are interested in that info hash (that's the basic idea). Piratically there is more to it as often a tracker would also offer an interface and/or might implement strategies to limit who can download. An example for a tracker software would be [opentracker](http://erdgeist.org/arts/software/opentracker/).

## Peer Exchange Protocols

The technologies (mainly DHT nowadays from what I know) aim to replace trackers. Trackers are a single point of failure after all. So the idea (also describes in the magnet link question) is that you have a swarm that replace the tracker. But essentially it's the same process that is necessary.

Comment: as a test setup I am trying it over LAN with a tracker that is on the same lan, but I am getting very slow upload speeds, i.e in KBs instead of MBs as there is nothing limiting the speed. But why is this so?

Comment: This is the screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/8xpJq

Comment: I don't use µTorrent, maybe you limit the upload? Did you check the other settings that are available?

Comment: In case whoever downvotes comes along again, would you mind explaining what's wrong about the answer?

Comment: I guess they are pissed because you are helping me understand a method that is usually used for piracy? Or it doesn't directly answer the question? Either way. Come to think of it. i might have throttled upload speed. Will be back with the update tomorrow.

Comment: Don't swear, it's not productive. This answer might actually have issue and I still believe Torrent isn't the best approach for this. But as you seem to be rather set on using this, it just tries to clear up the terminology. Going by your Screenshot in the lower right there is an L which could indicate Limit.

Comment: your detailed text along with links helped me understand the method and I have succeeded. I setup a tracker on my downloading side via Bitstorm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Another option I came across: add a **[RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS)** server. There are plenty around, if you don't want to develop one.

1. Generate monthly incremental backups.
2. Generate a **.torrent** file for each incremental backup.
3. Publish this **.torrent** file on your RSS application.
4. Configure the Torrent clients to automatically add Torrents from that RSS url.